Manufacture replacement spring for Kodak Duaflex IV shutter
I am fixing a Kodak Duaflex IV and I need a new spring for the shutter.  This is a picture of the spring
The spring is labeled "50" in this diagram of the shutter from the patent

I have some spring steel of the right thickness and I have found many videos on the internet with instructions to make springs with multiple coils, but this spring has just a single loop and I am not sure how to make the two clasps at the ends of the spring to attach to the two posts in the shutter.
Any ideas?

I would just bend them around suitably sized dowels/mandrels, and bend the clasping turns using needle nose/jewelers pliers. The final bend at the free ends could also be bent with pliers rather than slower radius shown.
